# Diffirentiability of the function $f(x,y) = x + y + |x|^{\alpha}|y|^{\beta}$ at the point $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

> The function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as: $f(x,y) = x + y + |x|^{\alpha}|y|^{\beta}$
>
> $\alpha > 0$ and $\beta > 0$
>
> What is the sufficient and necessary condition on $(\alpha, \beta)$ for $f$ to be differentiable at $(0,0)$ ?

---

By definition, $f$ is differentiable at the point $(0,0)$ if:

$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{|x + y + |x|^{\alpha}|y|^{\beta}|}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} = 0$$

We have: $$ \frac{|x + y + |x|^{\alpha}|y|^{\beta}|}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \leq \frac{|x + y|}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} + \frac{|x|^{\alpha}|y|^{\beta}}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} $$

I can get the condition using polar coordinates if I had  to deal only with:

$$\frac{|x|^{\alpha}|y|^{\beta}}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$$

but the term $ \frac{|x + y|}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} $ is blocking me.

How can I proceed?

Comment: your definition of differentiability is wrong, because you're already assuming that if the derivative exists, it is the zero linear map. As a sanity check, consider the special case $\alpha = 2, \beta=2$. Then, clearly the derivative at the origin will NOT be the zero map. This is why you're having trouble

Comment: @peek-a-boo $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ and the partial derivatives are both $0$. The differential at $(0,0)$ is the sum of the partial derivatives which is $0$. Am I wrong?

Comment: Instead, consider the function $g(x,y) = x+y$. $g$ is easily shown to be linear and hence differentiable ($C^{\infty}$ even). Also, let $h(x,y) = |x|^{\alpha}|y|^{\beta}$. As a first reduction step, using the fact that $f=g+h$ and that $g$ is already known to be differentiable, prove  that $f$ is differentiable at the origin if and only if $h$ is.

Comment: Sure, $f$ is continuous at the origin, but what does that have to do with anything (maybe it does, but I dont see the relevance yet, perhaps you should elaborate)? Are the partial derivatives really zero? Do they even exist in the first place? Note that $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(x+y) = 1$ (and this is true regardless where you evaluate the derivative). So, the $x+y$ terms will make the partial derivatives of $f$ (if they exist) nonzero

Comment: @peek-a-boo $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}h(0,0) = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} h(0,0)= 0 $. In this case, $h$ is differentiable if :  $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{|x|^{\alpha}|y|^{\beta}}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} = 0$. Am I correct?

Comment: (You didn't write the h in the second equal sign btw) but yes, you're right. For ANY $\alpha, \beta > 0$, the partial derivatives of $h$ at the origin exist and are equal to zero (if you can prove this, good). So, yes, $h$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ if and only if $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{|x|^{\alpha}|y|^{\beta}}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}} = 0$. So now all you have to do is figure out necessary and suffiecient conditions on $(\alpha, \beta)$ for this to happen

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you so much for your help.